# Growth of a certain class of smooth numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to solve this problem. Let us say that a number $n$ is *smooth* if it does not have prime factors bigger than $\sqrt{n}$. Let $f$ be the function that counts the smooth numbers between $1$ and $x$. How can I prove that there exist two constants $c_1>0$ and $c_2<1$ such that for every $x$ sufficiently big $c_1 x < f(x) < c_2 x$?

I would appreciate if you can give me just a small hint. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: the numbers you don't want to count can all be written as $n=pm$ with $p>\sqrt n$ and $m\le x/p$: sort them by their $p$ and count that way. (PS: the term "smooth", while older, is overloaded in mathematics—"friable" is a more modern and descriptive term for numbers without large prime factors.)

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong. Given a positive real number $x$, the number of integers i want to bound is given by $[x]$ minus all the numbers which i describe in the next sentence. These numbers are, for each prime $p$, of the form $n=mp$ where $m$ is less than $x/p$ so that the product does not exceed $x$ and $m$ is less than $p$, since $p>\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: I have found that given a prime number $p$ there are $p-1$ numbers that are non friable because they are divided by $p$: those are, as you said the multiples of $mp$ for $m=1,\dots,p-1$. If I am cousidering the number up to x, then I must distinguish whether the prime $p$ is less than $\sqrt{x}$. Then I split the two sum and apply the prime number theorem on the first sum and the asimptotic expression for the reciprocal sum of the primes